# WordPress is_user_logged_in() return false on home page and true in inner pages

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am having a strange problem with WordPress default function

```
is_user_logged_in()
```

When I visit my home page after login it return false means I am not logged in and When I visit inner pages it say I am logged in. I am trying to fix it from last 2 days so any help will be appreciated.

More Details

My website has ssl installed. so homepage url is https://www.example.com

For login I am using ajax function where I use JavaScript redirect after setting the following function

```
    wp_signon( $login_data, true );
    $registerUserSuccess = 4;
```

so if status is 4 I redirect user to my account page after sign in.

```
   <?php $profile = home_url('/')."my-account"; ?>
    var delay = 1000;
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '<?php echo $profile; ?>';}, delay);
```

Anybody please help me

Comment: You mean when you visit admin pages?

Comment: Thanks for your help. No when I visit home page in front end. Basically after 
login it redirect me to my acccount page and when I click on home page link or logo it navigate to home page. There user seems logout and when I hit refresh button it comes login again. If you would like I can share my website url with you

Comment: Strange thing is that I keep clicking on home page it remains logout but If I click on browser refresh button or press F5 then it seem logged in and stay logged in.

Comment: I resolved it. For those who having same problem I just replaced this line in my landing page where user comes after login

global $current_user, $td_user_id, $td_user_info;
get_currentuserinfo();

with global $current_user, $td_user_id, $td_user_info;
wp_get_current_user();

as first is deprecated. And seems not work perfectly with wp_signon()

Comment: Not good using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

`is_user_logged_in()` keeps session only for `./wp/*` ... if your members site is one dir up, it doesn't have those cookies... probably fixable by editing a core... but not an easy way to do that.